# Replacement of numbers between parentheses

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to convert this string:

```
PLK4(-110), RAB6B(-38), PSD2(-71), DMC1(-181), GRIN2A(-92), PTGFRN(-62,-51), KIAA0040(-307), NFIB(-552,-39), CHST2(-508),
```

to a data frame like this:

```
PLK4
RAB6B
PSD2
DMC1
GRIN2A
PTGFRN
KIAA0040
NFIB
CHST2
```

I need to replace (-number,...) and after that convert string to a data frame. For the first part, I used `sed` command:

```
sed 's/([0-9],)/ /g' file.txt > file2.txt
```

but I wasn't successful.

Comment: Can you add the `sed` command you tried? Also, would the text to be extracted always start with an uppercase letter?

Comment: What do you mean by "data frame"?  It seems like you just want `sed -e 's/([^)]*),/ /g' input | tr -s ' ' \\n`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: _ I used sed command in bash, but I wasn't successful._ .... This is not really a helpful error description. For programming problems, post the code you have tried, and explain in what respect it is not working.

Comment: If they always start with uppercase character, you can use `grep -Eo '[A-Z][^(]+' --group-separator='\n'`

Comment: please *update the question* with the `sed` code you attempted as well as the (wrong) results generated by said code

Comment: @ William Pursell, I used the code you provided and its worked. thank you so much.

Comment: @ William Pursell, and about data frame, I meant that after removing parentheses, I intend to convert results as a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char `RS` and `\s`:

```
$ awk -v RS='[(][^)]*),\\s*' '1' file
PLK4
RAB6B
PSD2
DMC1
GRIN2A
PTGFRN
KIAA0040
NFIB
CHST2
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk -F'[(][^)]*), *' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) print $i}' file
PLK4
RAB6B
PSD2
DMC1
GRIN2A
PTGFRN
KIAA0040
NFIB
CHST2
```

or:

```
$ awk -v ORS= '{gsub(/[(][^)]*), */,RS)} 1' file
PLK4
RAB6B
PSD2
DMC1
GRIN2A
PTGFRN
KIAA0040
NFIB
CHST2
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed 's/([^)]*), */\n/g' file.txt`

`grep -Po '\w+(?=\()' file.txt`

Sed:  Substitute the parenthetical with a linebreak.  Matches `([^)]*), *` -- that is, match everything between open and next closing paren, a comma, and optional space.   Replace all that with a linebreak.

Grep: Match only word characters followed by a nonconsuming group that matches open paren.